# Converting NTF to TIF using ArcGIS Pro in order to run FLAASH Correction

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, envi, flaash

I received worldview 2 files but some are in the .ntf while others are in the .tiff format. I am able to work and FLAASH the files that are in the .tiff format but I am unable to FLAASH the .ntf files. When I convert the .ntf files to .tiff in ArcGIS Pro it seems that it loses a lot of the metadata and I can’t run FLAASH anymore.

Is there a workaround to exporting the .ntf file to a .tiff while preserving the metadata to perform the atmospheric corrections?

Comment: Are you using the ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap application of ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: I am using ArcGIS Pro but also have access to ArcMap if needed.